# Microsoft Azure SqlSiteMapProvider Issue

Tags: sql, azure, sitemap, provider, sqlsitemapprovider

I'm trying to migrate my company website to a Azure Server but I'm getting problems with Sql SiteMap Provider.

I'm always getting this error: **Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'SqlSiteMapProvider'.**

Hope someone could help me how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

The problem is in Azure on custom sitemap types we have to put the full namespace.

At the old website We have this:

```
<add name="AspNetSqlSiteMapProvider" type="SqlSiteMapProvider" ...
```

For Azure We need to put it like this:

```
<add name="AspNetSqlSiteMapProvider" type="Site_Base.SqlSiteMapProvider" ...
```